# Searching an IMAP mailbox by skSince/skSentSince ignores the time portion of the TDateTime

Tags: delphi, imap, indy

In my app (Windows 10, Delphi 10.4) I use `TIdIMAP4` to search a mailbox for new emails, like this:

```
SelectMailBox(msgBox);
SetLength(SearchInfo, 1);
SearchInfo[0].Date := lastReceivedMessageDateTime+1/86400;// one second after the last received mail
SearchInfo[0].SearchKey := skSentSince; //skSince; 
try
   if SearchMailBox(SearchInfo)
   and (High(MailBox.SearchResult) > -1) then
   try
      msgs := High(MailBox.SearchResult)+1;
      ....
```

But I see that it returns all the mails of the starting day, ignoring the time of this day.
What am I missing?

Comment: You’re missing that the IMAP search language only specifies search times in days, and has no support for times.  See RFC 3501 for details.  It would be better to search by UIDs.

Comment: @Max. Do you mean searching for UIDs > lastUID ?